# Multiplayer card game on server using RPC

Tags: java, python, optimization, webserver, multiplayer

Basically I want a Java, Python, or C++ script running on a server, listening for player instances to: join, call, bet, fold, draw cards, etc and also have a timeout for when players leave or get disconnected.

Basically I want each of these actions to be a small request, so that players could either be processes on same machine talking to a game server, or machines across network.

Security of messaging is not an issue, this is for learning/research/fun.

My priorities:

1. Have a good scheme for detecting when players disconnect, but also be able to account for network latencies, etc before booting/causing to lose hand.
2. Speed. I'm going to be playing millions of these hands as fast as I can.
3. Run on a shared server instance (I may have limited access to ports or things that need root)

My questions:

1. Listen on ports or use sockets or HTTP port 80 apache listening script? (I'm a bit hazy on the differences between these).
2. Any good frameworks to work off of?
3. Message types? I'm thinking JSON or Protocol Buffers.
4. How to make it FAST?

Thanks guys - just looking for some pointers and suggestions. I think it is a cool problem with a lot of neat things to learn doing it.

Comment: The most important decision is which framework to use. And if this is a learning experience, the most important question is what you want to learn. Are you interested in designing REST services, or internet protocols? Learning a mid-level framework like Twisted or asio, or a high-level container like Tomcat or JBoss? (In general, a container will mean much less code but a bit more management.) Do you have any preference between the three languages? But beyond that, there are questions like: How much data needs to be shared between client sessions?

Comment: great questions. my ultimate goal is a "testing playground" with which to test out different AIs and machine learning techniques to play the game. the clients need not share anything, they are just playing each other and learning, using the server as a game keeper.

Comment: You should've started by stating all the players are non-humans. Why do you need a network then? Just instantiate the AI's playing in a game in the same machine and have them exchange state through memory. You'll achieve much greater performance by eliminating the network than any computational gains obtained from running each AI in their own machine. The AI computations needn't even be parallel.

Comment: "Playing each other" implies that they _do_ need to share something. Where is the game state? If it's on the server, then clearly there's session information being shared between two players' connections. If it's entirely on the clients, you don't need a server at all, as @EliAlgranti suggests. (Even if you _do_ need distributed computing, p2p would make a whole lot more sense, because any server is obviously going to be the primary bottleneck.)

Comment: @EliAlgranti yes, definitely it would be faster all on one machine. however, I want others to be able to plug in their AIs to the system and try them out remotely over the network against others - basically the server keeps track of the game state and is in control of drawing cards, etc. And the idea is that if I wanted I could change the timeout to seconds scale and play the AIs as a human.

Comment: In that case, JSON-RPC over HTTP has a couple of additional advantages. First, the barrier to entry for writing a client (AI or human) will be lower than with a custom protocol. Second, you can write an AJAX client pretty easily, so humans who want to join in just need to go to your website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as frameworks goes, [Ginkgo](http://ginkgo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) looks promising for building a network service (which is what you're doing). The Python is very straightforward, and the asynchronicity enabled by [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) lets you do asynchronous things without generally having to worry about callbacks. The gevent core also gives you access to a [lot of building blocks](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=gevent&submit=search).

Rather than having lots of services communicating over ports, you might look into either **1)** a good message queue, like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/), or **2)** a distributed coordination server, like [Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/).

That being said, what you aim to do is difficult, especially if you're not familiar with the basics. It's a worthwhile endeavor to learn about those basics.

Don't worry about speed at first. Get it working, then make it scale. Of course, there are directions you can go that will make it easier to scale in the future. [Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) in particular gives you easy-to-implement primitives for scaling horizontally (i.e. multiple workers sharing the load). In particular, see the [Zookeeper recipe book](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/recipes.html) and their corresponding [python implementations](https://kazoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) (courtesy of the [kazoo](https://kazoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), a gevent-based client library).

Don't forget that "fast" also means optimizing your own development time, for quicker iterations and less time cursing your development environment. So use Python, which will let you get up and running quickly now, and optimize later if you really truly start to bind on CPU time or memory use. (With this particular application, you're far more likely to bind on network IO.)

Comment: +1. Good explanation about horizontal scaling and rapid development being the keys to performance on the server side. I'm not sure I'd use Gingko in place of something more mature… but the idea of a complete framework built on top of gevent is pretty nifty. It would be great to not have to spend 80% of your time learning how to connect up callbacks when there's so much else to learn.

Comment: Thanks. Ginkgo *is* less mature than I might like, but it's what I know about, it's got better-than-average documentation (that is, it *has* docs), and in my own experience it's straightforward enough to do things with minimal boilerplate. I'd be pleased as punch to learn about any other gevent-based service frameworks with documentation. :)

Comment: My point was that I don't know of any other gevent-based framework that's better than Ginkgo, so I *might* use Gingko even though it's not as mature as I'd like and I'd still be wary. Anyway, you've convinced me to play with it, and your answer doesn't say any more than that it "looks promising", so your answer definitely deserves the +1 I gave it.

Answer (score 2):

Anything else? Maybe a cup of coffee to go with your question :-)

Answering your question from the ground up would require several books worth of text with topics ranging from basic TCP/IP networking to scalable architectures, but I'll try to give you some direction nevertheless.

Questions:

1. Listen on ports or use sockets or HTTP port 80 apache listening script? (I'm a bit hazy on the differences between these).

I would venture that if you're not clear on the definition of each of these maybe designing an implementing a service that will be "be playing millions of these hands as fast as I can" is a bit hmm, over-reaching? But don't let that stop you as they say "ignorance is bliss."

1. Any good frameworks to work off of?

I think your project is a good candidate for Node.js. There main reason being that Node.js is relatively scaleable and it is good at hiding the complexity required for that scalability. There are downsides to Node.js, just Google search for 'Node.js scalability critisism'.
The main point against Node.js as opposed to using a more general purpose framework is that scalability is difficult, there is no way around it, and Node.js being so high level and specific provides less options for solving though problems.
The other drawback is Node.js is Javascript not Java or Phyton as you prefer.

1. Message types? I'm thinking JSON or Protocol Buffers.

I don't think there's going to be a lot of traffic between client and server so it doesn't really matter I'd go with JSON just because it is more prevalent.

1. How to make it FAST?

The real question is how to make it scalable. Running human vs human card games is not computationally intensive, so you're probably going to run out of I/O capacity before you reach any computational limit.
Overcoming these limitations is done by spreading the load across machines. The common way to do in multi-player games is to have a list server that provides links to identical game servers with each server having a predefined number of slots available for players.
This is a variation of a broker-workers architecture were the broker machine assigns a worker machine to clients based on how busy they are. In gaming users want to be able to select their server so they can play with their friends.

Related:

1. Have a good scheme for detecting when players disconnect, but also be able to account for network latencies, etc before booting/causing to lose hand.

Since this is in human time scales (seconds as opposed to miliseconds) the client should send keepalives say every 10 seconds with say 30 second session timeout.
The keepalives would be JSON messages in your application protocol not HTTP which is lower level and handled by the framework.
The framework itself should provide you with HTTP 1.1 connection management/pooling which allows several http sessions (request/response) to go through the same connection, but do not require the client to be always connected. This is a good compromise between reliability and speed and should be good enough for turn based card games.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd start with classic LAMP. Take a stock Apache server, and a mysql database, and put your Python scripts in the cgi-bin directory. The fact that they're sending and receiving JSON instead of HTTP doesn't make much difference.

This is obviously not going to be the most flexible or scalable solution, of course, but it forces you to confront the actual problems as early as possible.

The first problem you're going to run into is game state. You claim there is no shared state, but that's not right—the cards in the deck, the bets on the table, whose turn it is—that's all state, shared between multiple players, managed on the server. How else could any of those commands work? So, you need some way to share state between separate instances of the CGI script. The classic solution is to store the state in the database.

Of course you also need to deal with user sessions in the first place. The details depend on which session-management scheme you pick, but the big problem is how to propagate a disconnect/timeout from the lower level up to the application level. What happens if someone puts $20 on the table and then disconnects? You have to think through all of the possible use cases.

Next, you need to think about scalability. You want millions of games? Well, if there's a single database with all the game state, you can have as many web servers in front of it as you want—John Doe may be on server1 while Joe Schmoe is on server2, but they can be in the same game. On the other hand, you can a separate database for each server, as long as you have some way to force people in the same game to meet on the same server. Which one makes more sense? Either way, how do you load-balance between the servers. (You not only want to keep them all busy, you want to avoid the situation where 4 players are all ready to go, but they're on 3 different servers, so they can't play each other…).

The end result of this process is going to be a huge mess of a server that runs at 1% of the capacity you hoped for, that you have no idea how to maintain. But you'll have thought through your problem space in more detail, and you'll also have learned the basics of server development, both of which are probably more important in the long run.

If you've got the time, I'd next throw the whole thing out and rewrite everything from scratch by designing a custom TCP protocol, implementing a server for it in something like Twisted, keeping game state in memory, and writing a simple custom broker instead of a standard load balancer.

Comment: yeah my current plan is django/python + mysql + json over HTTP, just was wondering. cool, thanks. whats a broker? google/wikipedia were not that helpful. just basically a web service that keeps state for clients that connect / have a session?

Comment: Sorry; "broker" is a very overloaded term. What I meant was that it would have enough information about players and games that you could expand it from simple load balancing to, e.g., rejoining games, finding friends, etc., and/or game-specific load-balancing (e.g., if 3 players are waiting for a 4th on server 2, the next connection goes to server 2, even is server 1 has less load).